# Login to Spotify using HTMLUnit

Tags: java, authentication, spotify

I try to log me on Spotify (in France, https://accounts.spotify.com/fr-FR/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Ffr%2Flogged-in%2F) using HTMLUnit but my code didn't work, this is my code:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class MainCheck {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
        HtmlPage page1;
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(true);
        try {
            page1 = webClient.getPage("https://accounts.spotify.com/fr-FR/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Ffr%2Flogged-in%2F");
            final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page1.getElementById("ng-pristine ng-valid-sp-disallow-chars ng-invalid ng-invalid-required");
            System.out.println(page1.getForms());

            final HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue("SE CONNECTER").get(0);
            final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("email");
            textField.setValueAttribute("jon@jon.com");
            final HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = form.getInputByName("pass");
            textField2.setValueAttribute("ahhhh");
            try {
                final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to:

- open the url "https://accounts.spotify.com/fr-FR/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Ffr%2Flogged-in%2F"
  (Spotify for France)
- enter the email in "Nom d'utilisateur ou adresse e-mail"
- enter the password in "Mot de passe"
- and then to click on the button "SE CONNECTER"

I searched on stackoverflow.com:

- [Login to gmail using HtmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428699/login-to-gmail-using-htmlunit)
- [Login to vBulletin using htmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957622/login-to-vbulletin-using-htmlunit)
- [login to vbulletin forums using htmlunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033257/login-to-vbulletin-forums-using-htmlunit)
- [Login to Google Account using HtmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317851/login-to-google-account-using-htmlunit)
- [Unable to login to WSJ using HtmlUnit/HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012157/unable-to-login-to-wsj-using-htmlunit-httpclient)

But nothing work :/
Can you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please provide more details. Do you get some exception?

Comment: @RBRi This is the console https://hastebin.com/litikeqita.xml

Comment: The link leads to a black page. I fear that is not the output you get. There is a HtmlUnit user mailing list - maybe it is easier to send a good old mail with an attachment.